# spree install errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, installation, spree

i am following the guide at http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

all's ok until i run

```
bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
```

rake says

```
Don't know how to build task 'spree_sample:load'
```

if i decide to skip that and do

```
rake db:bootstrap
```

it says

```
Table 'myproject_development.countries' doesn't exist
```

if alternatively i run

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rake spree_sample:load
```

it also says

```
Don't know how to build task 'spree_sample:load'
```

if i still continue that and run

```
rake db:admin:create
```

i get another error:

```
no such file to load -- /home/pavel/cetsy/db/sample/users.rb
```

bundler information:

> ...
>
> Using rails (3.0.9)
>
> ...
>
> Using spree_core (0.60.1)
>
> Using spree_auth (0.60.1)
>
> Using spree_api (0.60.1)
>
> Using spree_dash (0.60.1)
>
> Using spree_promo (0.60.1)
>
> Using spree_sample (0.60.1)
>
> Using spree (0.60.1)

Comment: I think it may be an issue with using 3.0.9, I just tried the steps using rails '3.1.1' and spree '0.7' and the above steps worked perfectly.

Comment: Did you not run `rails g spree:site`?

Comment: in my case creating new app with same steps but with 3.1.1/0.60.1 produced exact same results

Comment: yes, i run "rails g spree:site". actually, i just tried creating new app,  adding "gem 'spree', '0.7'" to Gemfile and running "bundle update". the result of that was that "rails g spree:site" gave "Could not find generator spree:site"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon was right, upgrading rails and spree to 3.1.1/0.70 partially solved the issue

now, running

> bundle exec rake spree_sample:load

still produces

> Don't know how to build task 'spree_sample:load'

but skipping this step lets me finish installing spree without other problems